# Realm Error on Assigning Object

Tags: swift, realm

I'm using Realm with Swift on my iOS project.

I have a Realm object which in turn contains references to other Realm objects. I noticed some strange behavior where setting the reference will cause an primary key error as follows:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', 
reason: 'Can't create object with existing primary key value '35834'.'
```

What's strange is that I'm just setting a reference. I have two objects (ObjectA and ObjectB) each of which has it's own primary key.

```
public class ObjectA: Object{
    dynamic public var objectReference:ObjectB?
```

When I do this the first time with that objectReference it works fine. It's just when I do subsequent updates with that same objectReference that it seems to go wrong.

If I first make a call to add the object to the Realm with update:true things are ok, but that feels hacky. Maybe it's the right way to go? Or maybe I've missed a point with Realm. Does assigning an object to another implicitly attempt to add the object to the Realm?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which API you're using to write to Realm. Using `realm.add(_:update:)` with `update` set to false will always try to add that object as a new copy of that object and any child objects. If you have a primary key, it will trigger the exception you saw above. If you don't have primary keys, it will add a whole second copy of that object (Which you might not want either).

The point of `realm.add(_:update: true)` is mainly for REST API patterns, where you might be constantly updating an object from a server, and Realm can intelligently add the object to the database the first time, and then simply update that object on subsequent calls.

If both objects are already in Realm, and you know you don't need that add-or-update logic, it might be more appropriate to directly assign the child object instead of using the `add` API:

```
let realm = try! Realm()

let parentObject: ObjectA = ...
let childObject: ObjectB = ...

try! realm.write {
   parentObject.objectReference = childObject
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It turns out that the problem was that I was storing ObjectB in Realm before assigning it. This was ok the first time that the assignment was made, but any time the object was assigned after that it was throwing the exception. Makes sense in a way